# Output of Java XML comparison tool

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I wrote a short Java Tool for XML comparison using XMLunit. 
For my purposes it’s necessary to ignore the node order and some special element names. 
The attached code is working fine for that. Now I would like to get the differences. Unfortunately  diff.toString() gives me all the differences also the “not identical” ones, but I would like to reduce the output to the real different ones because the “not identical” ones are caused by the dissentient order of the nodes.

My Output looks like:

```
org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff

[not identical] Expected sequence of child nodes '770' but was '771' …

[not identical] Expected sequence of child nodes '771' but was '772' …

[not identical] Expected sequence of child nodes '772' but was '773' …
…
[different] Expected text value 'Dominik' but was 'Dominika' - comparing <VORNAMEN ...>Dominik</VORNAMEN>…
```

My code is:

```
public void vergleichen()
{
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(Boolean.TRUE);
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(Boolean.TRUE);
    String f1 = lesen(quelle);
    String f2 = lesen(vergleich);

    try {
        Diff diff = new Diff(f1, f2);
        diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());

        diff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreNamedElementsDifferenceListener("ex1","ex2","ex3"));
        boolean result = diff.similar();

        if (result==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Die Dateien sind gleich");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Es wurden Unterschiede gefunden");
            System.out.println(diff.toString())
        }
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Diff` inside a `DetailedDiff` before invoking `similar` and the `DetailedDiff` will allow you to access all `Difference`s. You can then filter those `Difference`s on whether they are `recoverable` and invoke `toString` on the non-recoverable ones yourself.